# why doesn't my web scraper work? Python3 - requests, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been following [this python tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVNJOiTBi_8) for a while, and I made a web scrawler, similar to the one in the video.

Language: Python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/7/computer-office.html?trafficChannel=main&catName=computer-office&CatId=7&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&g=n&page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,  'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'item-title'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

And this is the output that the program gives:

```
PS D:\development> & C:/Users/hirusha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "d:/development/Python/TheNewBoston/Python/one/web scrawler.py"n/TheNewBoston/Python/one/web scrawler.py"
PS D:\development>
```

What can I do?

---

Before this, I had an error, the code was:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
```

i changed this to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,  'html.parser')
```

and the error was gone,

the error i got here was:

```
d:/development/Python/TheNewBoston/Python/one/web scrawler.py:10: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 10 of the file d:/development/Python/TheNewBoston/Python/one/web scrawler.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: It needed a specified parser and now you have provided one. What is the current problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no results as the class you are targeting is not present until the webpage is rendered, which doesn't happen with requests.

Data is dynamically retrieved from a `script` tag. You can regex the JavaScript object holding the data and parse with json to get that info.

The error you show was due to a parser not being specified originally; which you rectified.

```
import re, json, requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/category/7/computer-office.html?trafficChannel=main&catName=computer-office&CatId=7&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&g=n&page=1')
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\.runParams = (\{".*?\});', r.text, re.S).group(1))
df = pd.DataFrame([(item['title'], 'https:' + item['productDetailUrl']) for item in data['items']])
print(df)
```